# accessibilityLabel and Title the same for UIAutomation in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I watched Apple's video on UIAutomation and saw some online tutorials about it.  Most say to either set the accessibility label in code like:

```
self.helpButton.accessibilityLabel = @"helpButton";
self.helpButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
```

Or to use IB. When I try the above code, my script finds the button fine and I'm able to tap on it through my script.  However, if in my storyboard, I click the Accessibility Enabled checkbox, and then I make the label: helpButton, my code does not find this button.  When I log the elementTree, I get this:

```
UIAWindow ->
  UIAButton: name: Help rect: {...}
```

The title of my button is Help, but the accessibility label is set to helpButton.  I don't see why logElementTree() has the name of the button as Help (title in IB), instead of helpButton (accessibilityLabel).  Any thoughts?  Thanks!